# hive.metastore.uri at presto worker requires restart of any service?

Tags: thrift, presto, hive-metastore

I'm not sure this was already answered.

I've Presto setup with Co-coordinator, worker and metastores in docker containers over AWS EC2 instances, spread across Availability Zones. The following config is used at presto workers - `hive.metastore.uri=thrift://metastore1:9083,thrift://metastore2:9083,thrift://metastore3:9083`

If I change the order like follow [ from 1,2,3 to 3,2,1], do I need to take a restart of service at Presto worker? `hive.metastore.uri=thrift://metastore3:9083,thrift://metastore1:9083,thrift://metastore2:9083`

Answer (score 1):

Presto worker does not talk directly to Metastore, so you don't need to restart workers if this is the only configuration change.